# Texture doesn't show up on render mode

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv, baking

I'm new to blender and I tried to follow a tutorial on how to create a house. I unwrapped the and baked the textures in blender cycles, then assigned it onto a material in blender render. The texture just becomes all deformed.

.blend file [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I believe what's happening here is that it is rendering the wrong UV layout. So just select the right one.